# difference between pointer and pointer location

Tags: c, pointers

This code prints different values for i and &i and both of them are not equal to 10. Please explain me what those two numbers indicate.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int p=10;
    int *i=&p;
    printf("%d %d",i,&i);
}
```

[This is what the output look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejqwa.png)

Comment: How about `*i` ?

Comment: `i` is a pointer to `p` (broadly speaking `i` contains the address of `p`) while `&i` is a pointer to `i`... But is a a too basic concept to deserve a true answer on SO.

Comment: You should pick up a good book on C that explains what pointers are and how they work.

Comment: and passing a pointer value to `printf()` when you tell it to expect an integer causes Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @cleblanc, *i returns 10;

Comment: @Serge Ballesta, so made it clear. Thanks

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Basic is subjective. There's probably a duplicate though on this.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is an `integer pointer` that will be used to store address of a `integer variable`. In this case, `i` is stored in stack area of your main memory, when you print `&i` it means you print address of the place that storing `i`. When you print `i` it means you print value of `i`( value of `i` is address of `p` because you have assign `&p` to `i` by this line `int *i=&p;`). I hope it useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of your code with comments in the printfs.  Note that I added the third printf to reference your `int` that is in `p`

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int p=10;
    int *i=&p;
    printf("'i'  = %p is the address of the int stored in variable p\n",(void *)i);
    printf("'&i' = %p is the address of the pointer to an int called i\n",(void *)&i);
    printf("'*i' = %d is the int that is stored at the location in i which points to p\n",*i);
}
```

`'i'  = 0x7ffee4e63abc is the address of the int stored in variable p`
`'&i' = 0x7ffee4e63ab0 is the address of the pointer to an int called i`
`'*i' = 10 is the int that is stored at the location in i which points to p`

Comment: casting pointers to `unsigned int` is probably not a good idea. You should cast pointers to `void *` and print it with `%p`.

Comment: @Osiris . Updated per your comments.  Far better, thanks.